# How can I inject a constant into a directive's controller?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to dependency injections and have encountered a something I can't quite figure out. I have a constant located in a separate file and need it injected into the same file of my directive to be used in the directive's controller. I'm unsure of where I should be injecting the constants: in the controller or the directive? Here's some example code of what my files sort of look like.

First file:

```
angular.module('utilities')
    .constant('myOpts', {
        ...stuff
    });
```

Second file:

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            ... need the constant in here
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at **[DI-official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject it into the `.directive` function.

You do this by putting *square brackets around your function statement* (so that you are passing and array instead of a single function) and then prepending the string representation of your constant before the function, then adding it as a parameter of your function.

**Module file:**

```
angular.module('utilities')
    .constant('myOpts', {
        'stuff1': 'Stuff 1 Value',
        'stuff2': 'Stuff 2 Value'
    });
```

**Directive file:**

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('myDirective', ['myOpts', function(myOpts) {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            alert(myOpts.stuff1);
            alert(myOpts.stuff2);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Le-roy That's properly injected and invertere don't forget to inject the both modules that you declared into your root module.

Comment: Good point. Might want to capitalize 'Invertere' as it took me a few moments to realize what you were saying :)